# Compojure redirect

Tags: clojure, compojure

I have the following compojure rootes

```
   (defroutes app-routes
    (GET "/login" [] (views/login))
    (POST "/index.html"  req (auth/do-login req))
    (GET "/main" req (views/main req))
    (GET "/test" [] (redirect "/login"))
    (not-found "Not Found"))
```

And I wrap them with the following handlers

```
  (defn default-handler [routes]
    (wrap-defaults routes
                   (-> site-defaults
                       (assoc-in
                        [:security :anti-forgery] false))))

  (def http-handler
    (-> (default-handler app-routes)
        (wrap-stacktrace)
        (wrap-authentication backend)
        (wrap-authorization backend)
        (wrap-session)
        (wrap-params)
        (wrap-with-logger)))

  (defn -main []
    (run-jetty http-handler {:port 8000 :join? false}))
```

I run a ring server behind and nginx reverse proxy. The problem I face is with the redirection. I cannot properly redirect from compojure roots. Every redirection adds the hole address to the root path. For instance 
http://79.137.xx.xxx/test  redirects to  http://79.137.xx.xxx%2C79.137.xx.xxx/login instead of http://79.137.xx.xxx/login
To redirect from "/" to a uri one can add the following middlewere

```
2 (defn redirect* [handler uri]
 33   (fn  [request]
 34   ¦ (let  [k  (if  (contains? request :path-info)
 35   ¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ :path-info :uri) v  (get request k)]
 36   ¦ ¦ (if  (re-find #"/$" v)
 37   ¦ ¦ ¦ (ring.util.response/redirect uri)
 38   ¦ ¦ ¦ (handler request)))))
 39
```

And this works but I would prefer to avoid adding a middlewere for each redirection path

Comment: Problem seems to be related with the non-existance of dns. if I add  (GET "/test" [] (redirect "http://79.137.xx.xxx/login"))  it redirects